# Python string duplicates

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a list

```
a=['apple', 'elephant', 'ball', 'country', 'lotus', 'potato']
```

I am trying to find largest element in the list with no duplicates.

For example script should return "country" as it doesn't have any duplicates.

Please help

Comment: I need to find largest string in a list which doesn't have duplicate characters

Comment: It shouldn't return elephant because character "e" is repeated twice

Answer (score 2):

```
def has_dup(x):
    unique = set(x)  # pick unique letters
    return any([x.count(e) != 1 for e in unique])  # find if any letter appear more than once


def main():
    a = ['apple', 'elephant', 'ball', 'country', 'lotus', 'potato']
    a = [e for e in a if not has_dup(e)]  # filter out duplicates
    chosen = max(a, key=len)  # choose with max length
    print(chosen)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could also just write `max(a, key = len)` here.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['apple', 'elephant', 'ball', 'country', 'lotus', 'potato']

a = set(a)

no_dups = []
for word in a:
    counts = Counter(word)
    if all(v == 1 for v in counts.values()):
        no_dups.append(word)

print(max(no_dups, key = len))
```

Which follows this procedure:

- Converts `a` to a set, since we only need to look at a word once, just in case `a` contains duplicates.
- Creates a `Counter()` object of each word.
- Only appends words that have a count of 1 for each letter, using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all).
- Get longest word from this resultant list, using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max).

**Note:** This does not handle ties, you may need to do further work to handle this.